# Setting Error Message on Lightning:select

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to understand how to add custom error messaging to the lightning:select base component.

I understand that I can use the validity object to check if there is bad data and set a respective custom message. What I am having trouble understanding is how to apply it to this scenario:

1. I have a lightning:select component defined with the values "Red,Blue,Green".
2. Because I want to force a selection, I've added "-- None --" as the first value in the list.
3. So I have "-- None --,Red,Blue,Green"

How do I tell the base component that "-- None --" is invalid and an error needs to be shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic happens when you combine the `required`, `onchange`, and `messageWhenValueMissing` attributes together.

```
<aura:attribute name="colors" type="String[]" default="Red,Green,Blue"/>
<lightning:select aura:id="select" name="select" 
                  label="Select a Color" 
                  required="true" onchange="{! c.onChange }" 
                  messageWhenValueMissing="Choose one!">
    <option value="">-- None --</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.colors}" var="color">
            <option value="{!color}" text="{!color}"></option>
        </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

The error message specified by `messageWhenValueMissing` is shown when the first option is selected. You can also pair this solution with the `showHelpMessageIfInvalid` method to trigger the error from your JS controller.

Credits to [@Eugene Kashida](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/38461/eugene-kashida).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of focus() method available in lightning:input/select

You can use:

```
var allValid = cmp.find('field').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) { //inputCmp.reportValidity(); 
**inputCmp.focus();**
return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity(); 
}, true);
```

Then reset the focus to appropriate field and you'll see the all errors listed under the field.